# CrafterCMS: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab

Tags: groovy, content-management-system, crafter-cms

I cloned a new site that was created in an older version (3.0.x) but there are errors in instantiating a bean from a constructor.

I am not able to view or build the application context because of the error.
[image]

Heres's the runtime exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
```

Snippet of the jdbc class:

```
@Grab(group='org.springframework', module = 'spring-jdbc', version = '4.1.9.RELEASE')
@Grab(group='commons-dbcp', module='commons-dbcp', version='1.2.2')
@Grab(group='com.sap.cloud.db.jdbc', module='ngdbc', version='2.2.16')

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate

class SAPJdbcTemplate extends JdbcTemplate {

    def SAPJdbcTemplate(BasicDataSource rq1DataSource, global) {
        super()
        rq1DataSource.setDriverClassName(global.getProperty("studio.db.driverClassName"))
        rq1DataSource.setUrl(global.getProperty("studio.db.url"))
        rq1DataSource.setUsername(global.getProperty("studio.db.username"))
        rq1DataSource.setPassword(global.getProperty("studio.db.password"))
        this.setDataSource(rq1DataSource)
    }
}
```

Bean from `application-context.xml`

```
<bean id="SAPJdbcTemplate" class="com.troo.services.SAPJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="rq1DataSource"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="crafter.propertyResolver"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review this article

https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/projects/engine/api/script-sandbox-configuration.html#adding-dependencies-with-grapes

Crafter CMS has a Groovy security sandbox that you need to consider.